# Mixing relational and boolean conditions in java if statements

Tags: java, repast-simphony

How does combining `boolean` and non-boolean if statements in java work? Is there a particular way the conditional statements need to be written?

For example, the code below gives me different results every time.

Beetles are initialized as randomly male or female and at age 0.

```
public class BeetleAgent {
    public boolean isFemale;
    public int age;

    public BeetleAgent(boolean isFemale, int age) {
        // initialize class variables with arguments
    } 

    //age in days
    @ScheduledMethod(start = 1, interval = 1)
    public void trackAge () {
        this.setAge(getAge() + 1);
        System.out.println("Beetle is now " + this.getAge());

    }

    // adults mate after 1 week 
    @ScheduledMethod(start = 1, interval = 1)
    public void checkMate() { 
        if (this.getAge()== 7 && this.isFemale()) {
            System.out.println("Both are true, beetle can MATE.");
            mate();
        }
    }

    @ScheduledMethod(start = 1, interval = 1)
    public void checkMaleDeath() { 
        if (!this.isFemale() && this.getAge()== 13) {
            System.out.println("Both are true, male beetle can DIE.");
            maleDeath();
        }   
    }

    @ScheduledMethod(start = 1, interval = 1)
    public void checkFemaleDeath() {
        if (this.isFemale() && this.getAge() == 25) {
            System.out.println("Both are true, female beetle can DIE.");
            femaleDeath();
        }
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

I cant imagine java doesn't allow for mixing...

EDIT:

Context...

```
    Random random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        boolean isFemale = random.nextBoolean();
        int age = 0;
        BeetleAgent beetle = new BeetleAgent(context, geography, isFemale, age);
        context.add(beetle);
        beetleagentlist.add(beetle);
        Coordinate coord = new Coordinate(-79.6976, 43.4763);
        Point geom = fac.createPoint(coord);
        geography.move(beetle, geom);
    }
```

I have sysout code to see that I am indeed getting male and female beetles.
I also have sysout code to see that they are aging properly.

Sometimes, methods are skipped, as if the conditions are not met. Sometimes they all work properly.

Sorry the outputs are in code format, but its easiest. What I want is, if the beetles are age 7 and female, they will find a mate. If the beetles are age 13 and male, they will die. If the beetles are age 25 and female, they will die. Sometimes this happens:

```
Female: true
Female: true
Female: false
Female: false
Female: false
Female: true
Preparing to load a set of trees... 
6182 trees loaded!
Preparing to load the model...
1 model loaded!
Beetle is now 1
Beetle is now 1
Beetle is now 1
Beetle is now 1
Beetle is now 1
Beetle is now 1
Beetle is now 2
Beetle is now 2
Beetle is now 2
Beetle is now 2
Beetle is now 2
Beetle is now 2
Beetle is now 3
Beetle is now 3
Beetle is now 3
Beetle is now 3
Beetle is now 3
Beetle is now 3
Beetle is now 4
Beetle is now 4
Beetle is now 4
Beetle is now 4
Beetle is now 4
Beetle is now 4
Beetle is now 5
Beetle is now 5
Beetle is now 5
Beetle is now 5
Beetle is now 5
Beetle is now 5
Beetle is now 6
Beetle is now 6
Beetle is now 6
Beetle is now 6
Beetle is now 6
Beetle is now 6
Beetle is now 7
Beetle is now 7
Beetle is now 7
Beetle is now 7
Beetle is now 7
Beetle is now 7
Both are true, beetle can MATE.
Mating...
Both are true, beetle can MATE.
Mating...
Both are true, beetle can MATE.
Mating...
//sometimes this prints twice (should only print once)
Both are true, beetle can MATE.
Mating...
Both are true, beetle can MATE.
Mating...
Both are true, beetle can MATE.
Mating...
Beetle is now 8
Beetle is now 8
Beetle is now 8
Beetle is now 8
Beetle is now 8
Beetle is now 8
Beetle is now 9
Beetle is now 9
Beetle is now 9
Beetle is now 9
Beetle is now 9
Beetle is now 9
Beetle is now 10
Beetle is now 10
Beetle is now 10
Beetle is now 10
Beetle is now 10
Beetle is now 10
Beetle is now 11
Beetle is now 11
Beetle is now 11
Beetle is now 11
Beetle is now 11
Beetle is now 11
Beetle is now 12
Beetle is now 12
Beetle is now 12
Beetle is now 12
Beetle is now 12
Beetle is now 12
Beetle is now 13
Beetle is now 13
Beetle is now 13
Beetle is now 13
Beetle is now 13
Beetle is now 13
Both are true, male beetle can DIE.
Male beetle has died...
Both are true, male beetle can DIE.
Male beetle has died...
Both are true, male beetle can DIE.
Male beetle has died...
Beetle is now 14
Beetle is now 14
Beetle is now 14
Beetle is now 14
Beetle is now 14
Beetle is now 14
Beetle is now 15
Beetle is now 15
Beetle is now 15
Beetle is now 15
Beetle is now 15
Beetle is now 15
Beetle is now 16
Beetle is now 16
Beetle is now 16
Beetle is now 16
Beetle is now 16
Beetle is now 16
Beetle is now 17
Beetle is now 17
Beetle is now 17
Beetle is now 17
Beetle is now 17
Beetle is now 17
Beetle is now 18
Beetle is now 18
Beetle is now 18
Beetle is now 18
Beetle is now 18
Beetle is now 18
Beetle is now 19
Beetle is now 19
Beetle is now 19
Beetle is now 19
Beetle is now 19
Beetle is now 19
Beetle is now 20
Beetle is now 20
Beetle is now 20
Beetle is now 20
Beetle is now 20
Beetle is now 20
Beetle is now 21
Beetle is now 21
Beetle is now 21
Beetle is now 21
Beetle is now 21
Beetle is now 21
Beetle is now 22
Beetle is now 22
Beetle is now 22
Beetle is now 22
Beetle is now 22
Beetle is now 22
Beetle is now 23
Beetle is now 23
Beetle is now 23
Beetle is now 23
Beetle is now 23
Beetle is now 23
Beetle is now 24
Beetle is now 24
Beetle is now 24
Beetle is now 24
Beetle is now 24
Beetle is now 24
Beetle is now 25
Beetle is now 25
Beetle is now 25
Beetle is now 25
Beetle is now 25
Beetle is now 25
Both are true, female beetle can DIE.
Female beetle has died...
Both are true, female beetle can DIE.
Female beetle has died...
Both are true, female beetle can DIE.
Female beetle has died...
Beetle is now 26
Beetle is now 26
Beetle is now 26
Beetle is now 26
Beetle is now 26
Beetle is now 26

Sometimes this happens, where for in this example, but females dont die(not good). Also notice that the mate function only ran once as it should:
Female: false
Female: false
Female: false
Female: true
Female: true
Female: true
Preparing to load a set of trees... 
6182 trees loaded!
Preparing to load the model...
1 model loaded!
Beetle is now 1
Beetle is now 1
Beetle is now 1
Beetle is now 1
Beetle is now 1
Beetle is now 1
Beetle is now 2
Beetle is now 2
Beetle is now 2
Beetle is now 2
Beetle is now 2
Beetle is now 2
Beetle is now 3
Beetle is now 3
Beetle is now 3
Beetle is now 3
Beetle is now 3
Beetle is now 3
Beetle is now 4
Beetle is now 4
Beetle is now 4
Beetle is now 4
Beetle is now 4
Beetle is now 4
Beetle is now 5
Beetle is now 5
Beetle is now 5
Beetle is now 5
Beetle is now 5
Beetle is now 5
Beetle is now 6
Beetle is now 6
Beetle is now 6
Beetle is now 6
Beetle is now 6
Beetle is now 6
Beetle is now 7
Beetle is now 7
Beetle is now 7
Beetle is now 7
Beetle is now 7
Beetle is now 7
Both are true, beetle can MATE.
Mating...
Both are true, beetle can MATE.
Mating...
Both are true, beetle can MATE.
Mating...
Beetle is now 8
Beetle is now 8
Beetle is now 8
Beetle is now 8
Beetle is now 8
Beetle is now 8
Beetle is now 9
Beetle is now 9
Beetle is now 9
Beetle is now 9
Beetle is now 9
Beetle is now 9
Beetle is now 10
Beetle is now 10
Beetle is now 10
Beetle is now 10
Beetle is now 10
Beetle is now 10
Beetle is now 11
Beetle is now 11
Beetle is now 11
Beetle is now 11
Beetle is now 11
Beetle is now 11
Beetle is now 12
Beetle is now 12
Beetle is now 12
Beetle is now 12
Beetle is now 12
Beetle is now 12
Beetle is now 13
Beetle is now 13
Beetle is now 13
Beetle is now 13
Beetle is now 13
Beetle is now 13
Both are true, male beetle can DIE.
Male beetle has died...
Both are true, male beetle can DIE.
Male beetle has died...
Both are true, male beetle can DIE.
Male beetle has died...
Beetle is now 14
Beetle is now 14
Beetle is now 14
Beetle is now 14
Beetle is now 14
Beetle is now 14
Beetle is now 15
Beetle is now 15
Beetle is now 15
Beetle is now 15
Beetle is now 15
Beetle is now 15
Beetle is now 16
Beetle is now 16
Beetle is now 16
Beetle is now 16
Beetle is now 16
Beetle is now 16
Beetle is now 17
Beetle is now 17
Beetle is now 17
Beetle is now 17
Beetle is now 17
Beetle is now 17
Beetle is now 18
Beetle is now 18
Beetle is now 18
Beetle is now 18
Beetle is now 18
Beetle is now 18
Beetle is now 19
Beetle is now 19
Beetle is now 19
Beetle is now 19
Beetle is now 19
Beetle is now 19
Beetle is now 20
Beetle is now 20
Beetle is now 20
Beetle is now 20
Beetle is now 20
Beetle is now 20
Beetle is now 21
Beetle is now 21
Beetle is now 21
Beetle is now 21
Beetle is now 21
Beetle is now 21
Beetle is now 22
Beetle is now 22
Beetle is now 22
Beetle is now 22
Beetle is now 22
Beetle is now 22
Beetle is now 23
Beetle is now 23
Beetle is now 23
Beetle is now 23
Beetle is now 23
Beetle is now 23
Beetle is now 24
Beetle is now 24
Beetle is now 24
Beetle is now 24
Beetle is now 24
Beetle is now 24
Beetle is now 25
Beetle is now 25
Beetle is now 25
Beetle is now 25
Beetle is now 25
Beetle is now 25
Beetle is now 26
Beetle is now 26
Beetle is now 26
Beetle is now 26
Beetle is now 26
Beetle is now 26
Beetle is now 27
Beetle is now 27
Beetle is now 27
Beetle is now 27
Beetle is now 27
Beetle is now 27
Beetle is now 28
Beetle is now 28
Beetle is now 28
Beetle is now 28
Beetle is now 28
Beetle is now 28
```

Comment: I cant immediately see any problems with the if statements. Have you tried  using a debugger to check the variable values and why the conditionals are/aren't passing?

Comment: @blm Good to know. I have, but was unable to get the debugger to work for a repast simphony simulation the same way it works for a java class. I will try again.

Comment: Can you tell us what output you're getting exactly, and what is expected? I also can't find anything wrong with the code right now.

Comment: I believe the only problem you can have here is with your constructor inputs (`age` and `isFemale`). Can you show us what are you passing into it? We will need the desired output and the actual output too

Comment: By the way, there is no "non-boolean" mixing here. For example, `this.getAge() == 7` results in a `boolean` everytime. 
`"For example, the code below gives me different results every time. Beetles are initialized as randomly male or female and at age 0."` Since they are randomly initialized, shouldn't the results be different "every time"?

Comment: @FernandoCarvalhosa right thank you, I will edit

Comment: I have suggested some edits, take a look at it when you have time.

Comment: Thank you @FernandoCarvalhosa. Also I added in some more info.

Comment: @Aify I have added some info.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with the code as far as I can tell. If it's not working the way you want it to, can you please explain how you do want it to work?

Comment: @Aify can you please have a look at the edits.

Comment: I can see you've asked this on Repast-interest too.  Did the help there about random seed help you, or not?  I'm not sure that's the real issue here - is it really that on your second run, you have 3 females, but the `femaleDeath()` code block doesn't seem to be getting run?  If so - I'll edit your question to make it a bit clearer.  Then I might be able to help.

Comment: @JRichardSnape Richard, sorry for the delay. Nick suggested changing the priorities, for example @ScheduledMethod(start = 1, interval = 1, priority = 1.1), with different methods having different priorities 1.2, 1.3., 1.4 etc. and it worked. You can view the discussion on the repast mailing list documentation: http://sourceforge.net/p/repast/mailman/repast-interest/?viewmonth=201504

Comment: Sure - no problem.  I saw you got an answer on repast interest - I keep an eye on that.  Good call to post the answer to your own question here, too.  I edited it very slightly just to conform with code formatting on here... All the best!

Comment: BTW - if you disagree with my edit to your answer, you can always roll it back / amend it.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of a delay here, but the problem has been solved [in conversation with  Nick Collier, Repast Simphony co-creator on the repast interest list](http://sourceforge.net/p/repast/mailman/repast-interest/?viewmonth=201504).  He stated that all the methods are scheduled for the same priority which means they are using random helper (and thus a random seed) to decide their order.

Consequently, for example, `step()` may be called after `checkMate()` etc., and then in the next tick, the randomization occurs again and `step()` may be called before `checkMate()` etc. As a result an agent may be 13 and then 14 without any other methods being called when the agent is 13. If you want to specify the priority of the `@Scheduled` methods you can use the priority parameter or just stagger the start times (i.e. `step()` starts at `1`, then next method at `1.1` and so on.)

I found that my code works fine if the `death()` methods are the highest priority.